# the cookie is set to secure but your redirection url is non-tls error in keycloak-gatekeeper

Tags: docker-compose, keycloak

`[error] the cookie is set to secure but your redirection url is non-tls`

Facing this issue in my keycloak-gatekeeper container

Below my .conf file

```
discovery-url: http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/employee-ms/keys
skip-openid-provider-tls-verify: true
client-id: employee-admin

client-secret:

listen: :3000

enable-refresh-tokens: true
tls-cert:
tls-private-key:
redirection-url: http://localhost:8084/*
encryption-key: vGcLt8ZUdPX5fXhtLZaPHZkGWHZrT6aa
upstream-url: http://employee:80/
scopes:

resources:
- uri: /*
  methods:
  - GET

- uri: /admin/*
  methods:
  - GET
  roles:
  - openvpn:vpn-user
  - openvpn:prod-vpn

- uri: /admin/*
  methods:
  - GET
  roles:
  - openvpn:vpn-user
  - openvpn:commons-prod-vpn
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have everything in the error: `the cookie is set to secure but your redirection url is non-tls` (http protocol is non-tls protocol, so you need https protocol there).

There is default value `secure-cookie: true`, which is not compatible with your config `redirection-url: http://localhost:8084/*`.

You have 2 options:

1.) Configure TLS for your app, then you can have `redirection-url: https://localhost:8084/*`

2.) Disable secure cookie `secure-cookie: false`

Option 1 is better and more secure, because OIDC protocol requires TLS (you should to have TLS also for the Keycloak).

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to move the line `--secure-cookie false` above the option `--redirection-url http://localhost:3000`